# Transmission on Ubuntu: daemon is running but transmission-remote says Unauthorized User?

Tags: user-accounts, services, ubuntu-20.04, daemon, transmission

I installed Transmission on Ubuntu 20.04 with `sudo apt install transmission-daemon`.

After starting the service, when I try to get the status with `transmission-remote -si` I get:

> Unauthorized User

I have stopped the transmission-daemon service, edited the `/etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json` file and changed `"rpc-authentication-required": true` info `false`, restarted the service. But I keep getting the `Unauthorized User` error.

How do enable the possibility to interact with `transmission-remote` from my regular user account?

Answer (score 1):

My tests indicate that `transmission-daemon` rewrites the config file when it exits. In your case restarting the service restored the old setting (`"rpc-authentication-required": true`).

Stop the service, edit `/etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json` (like you did), only then start the service anew.

`transmission-remote -si` should now work.

---

It's possible to use `transmission-remote` with `"rpc-authentication-required": true`. After [setting up a password](https://superuser.com/q/113649/432690) you can use these options (from `man 1 transmission-remote`):

> `-n` `--auth username:password`
> Set the username and password for authentication
>
> `-ne` `--authenv`
> Set the authentication information from the `TR_AUTH` environment variable which must be formatted as `username:password`.
>
> `-N` `--netrc filename`
> Set the authentication information from a netrc file. See `netrc(5)` for more information.

<sup>("See `netrc(5)`" means "run `man 5 netrc`".)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Another way to run transmission is manually starting the daemon. You can add a parameter which eliminates the need for authentication.

```
transmission-daemon -T
```